# синтаксис в шаблонном классе

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

у нас есть только шаблон `Vector<T>` т.е. нет просто `Vector` какого - то специализированного, почему компилятор допускает такой синтаксис и нужно ли писать как ниже или нужно писать `Vector<T>` для параметров и возвращаемых значений

*строки вызывающие вопрос содержат комментарий*

```
template <class T>
class Vector {
protected:
  int length;
  T *mas;
public:
  Vector(int n);
  Vector(const Vector &z); // здесь в параметре не Vector<T>
  Vector(int n, T*a);
  Vector() {};
  ~Vector();
  int Length()const { return length; }
  T& operator[](int i);
  Vector& operator=(const Vector &right); // здесь в возвращаемом значении и параметре не Vector<T>
};
```

также здесь в определении метода

```
template <class T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector &right) {  // здесь в параметре не Vector<T>
  if(&right == this)
    return *this;
  if (right.length != length) {
    delete[] mas;
    length = right.length;
    mas = new T[length];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    mas[i] = right.mas[i];
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: А вы собирали то проект с инстанцированием?

Comment: @ヒミコ да, инстанцировал и использовал этот контейнер

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Внутри определения класса или его методов имя класса без параметров шаблона распознается как текущий инстанс этого шаблона (*current instantiation*). При этом во внешнем определении метода лидирующее возвращаемое значение еще не находится в контексте класса и поэтому не распознается без указания параметров шаблона, как и квалификатор `Vector<T>::`. Зато список аргументов и хвостовое возвращаемое значение уже будут в контексте класса и поэтому будут распознаваться и без указания параметров шаблона, как и при объявлении их внутри самого класса:

```
template <class T> auto
Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector &right) -> Vector& // здесь в возвращаемом значении и параметре не Vector<T>
```

Answer (score 3):

Члены шаблонного класса в свою очередь являются шаблонами, параметризованными при помощи аргументов шаблона.  Внутри области видимости `Vector<T>`  квалификация с `<T>` избыточна для имени шаблона( T является параметром, определенным внешным образом, и не участвуют в поисках имени в пределах одной специализации).

```
template <class T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector &right)
```

То же самое, что  и

```
 template <class T>
 Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector<T> &right)
```

Для возвращаемого значения  пока не определен область видимости, поэтому нужно указать имя с квалификатором `Vector<T>`